# Atomics dilemma: Can it even replace mutexes in any usable case?

Tags: gcc, atomic, c11

I'm using C11 atomics on a GNU compile embedded system (basically the same as std::atomics). I'm having trouble finding use cases for them, even in a very simple example I'm working on. Compare the following very simple program design: I want threadA to always write and threadB to read the information stored in a shared C-string.

**First try:**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define CONFIGURED_MAX 128

static char* shared_ptr_to_str;

char* get_that_char()
{
    char* str = NULL;
    __atomic_load(shared_ptr_to_str, str, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
    return str;
}

void threadA()
{
    char some[] = "Some String we got over network somehow";
    char * tmp_ptr = (char*) malloc(CONFIGURED_MAX);
    strncpy(tmp_ptr, some, CONFIGURED_MAX);
    __atomic_store(shared_ptr_to_str, tmp_ptr, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
}

void threadB()
{
    char* grabbed_str = get_that_char();

    // use grabbed_str somehow
}
```

This approach already has various problems:

1. Obviously it doesn't free the memory previously used to store the string when threadA iterates.
2. I'm holding on to a string in threadB() which could change at any moment.

When I try to fix those problems we arrive at situation B

**Second try:**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define CONFIGURED_MAX 128

static char* shared_ptr_to_str;

void cpy_that_char(char** to_fill)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    __atomic_load(shared_ptr_to_str, str, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
    *to_fill = (char*) malloc(strnlen(str, CONFIGURED_MAX));
    strncpy(*to_fill, str, CONFIGURED_MAX);
}

void threadA()
{
    char some[] = "Some String we got over network somehow";
    // free old buffer first
    free(shared_ptr_to_str);

    // fill in new stuff
    char * tmp_ptr = (char*) malloc(strnlen(some, CONFIGURED_MAX));
    strncpy(tmp_ptr, some, strnlen(some, CONFIGURED_MAX));
    __atomic_store(shared_ptr_to_str, tmp_ptr, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
}

void threadB()
{
    char* grabbed_str = NULL;
    cpy_that_char(&grabbed_str);

    // use grabbed_str somehow
}
```

Now I have made it even worse! Although I now get a local copy of the string for threadB (so it can do with it whatever it pleases), the atomic operations could still interfere with each other:

1. In threadA in between freeing and reassigning memory, cpy_that_char() could be called from threadB and encounter freed memory.
2. In function cpy_that char, strnlen() is already not guaranteed anymore to encounter the same shared_ptr_to_str when it is called after atomic load. The memory address could have been freed in between by threadA()

This means that I have to group the calls together: free() should be grouped with store in threadA and load should be grouped with strnlen() in cpy_that_char() from threadB.

And this basically means we're back at mutexes...

**In almost any case I encountered a situation like this**. It looks at first like it could be solved with atomics, but I fall back to mutexes again and again. Can anyone tell me what a real use case of atomics is and if I could have solved above example with atomics?

Comment: Look up "lock free algorithms".  There are some things that can be done with atomics instead of a mutex, though it can be quite challenging to get correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atomics are useful for primitives. For example, if thread A is processing items, and thread B is reporting progress, then thread A could write out the number of items processed into an atomic integer, and thread B could read it without needing a mutex.

They're also useful if there are multiple writers to the same value. In the example above, the progress counter could be atomically incremented from multiple processing threads.

Another use case is a "quit" flag, written from the main thread and read regularly from worker threads to check if they should exit.

In your case, where the data is not a primitive, there is nothing wrong with using a mutex. I suspect that any attempt to write it using atomics only would just end up reinventing a mutex anyway.

Comment: I suspected that too, but I thought maybe I'm just missing something. Thanks for your pragmatic answer!